# How to make Apple Mail.app to use SOCKS proxy configured by a PAC file

Tags: macos, proxy, gmail

For some reasons, I have to use a SOCKS proxy to access Gmail, otherwise, the connection will be blocked.

I tried the global SOCKS agent, and the Mail.app worked fine. Nevertheless, when I turned to use a PAC file to configure system agent automatically, the Mail.app wasn't able to access Gmail.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to set proxy in Mail.app? That is, Mail.app passes its web traffic to the SOCKS proxy while other apps won't be influenced.
2. If the answer to the first question is NO, then how to modify my PAC file to make Mail.app possible to access Gmail?

Any clues or suggestions would be appreciated.

---

More info:

OS version: OS X 10.9.5

Mail.app version: 7.3 (1878.6)

The PAC file:

```
var domains = {
  "l.google.com": 1,
  "gmail-imap.l.google.com": 1,
  "googlepages.com": 1,  
  "googlesile.com": 1, 
  "google.co.jp": 1, 
  "gaeproxy.googlecode.com": 1, 
  "sshtunnel.googlecode.com": 1, 
  "googleusercontent.com": 1, 
  "goagent.googlecode.com": 1, 
  "google.com": 1, 
  "googlevideo.com": 1, 
  "google.com.hk": 1, 
  "tuite.googlecode.com": 1, 
  "gfwinterceptor.googlecode.com": 1, 
  "gtap.googlecode.com": 1, 
  "googleapis.com": 1
};

var proxy = "SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:1080; SOCKS 127.0.0.1:1080; DIRECT;";

var direct = 'DIRECT;';

function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    var lastPos;
    do {
        if (domains.hasOwnProperty(host)) {
            return proxy;
        }
        lastPos = host.indexOf('.') + 1;
        host = host.slice(lastPos);
    } while (lastPos >= 1);
    return direct;
}
```

Comment: exactly same problem here. Looks like, mail.app doesn't interact with the pac file. But in my case, I've made this test: Before I open mail.app I've a terminal window showing the log of the server that serves my pac file, and I'm able to see that it load the pac. But doesn't delivers the traffic to the proxy. If I use Network settings-> Socks then it works. Have you solved it ?

Answer (score 3):

Try go to **Network Preferences**, select the network you want to set, and go to **Advanced -> Proxies**. Then, set **both** Automatic Proxy Configuration and SOCKS proxy. It works for me.

FYI, if you're using [Shadowsocks](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks) the PAC would probably be `http://127.0.0.1:8090/proxy.pac`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'd tried this before I posted this question. Unfortunately, however, the pac file failed to pass the traffic of Apple Mail into the socks tunnel. Indeed, set both PAC and Socks proxy would help, but I'm afraid this should only be owing to the Socks proxy. Nonetheless, socks proxy get all the web traffic by setting Socks Proxy in Network Pref., which is not I want.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old, but I had the same problem thanks to the great firewall. I didn't want to route ALL of my traffic through my proxy, so setting this in network preferences was not an option.

I thought the problem was because of the Mail app on mac, but actually it was just access to the IMAP and SMTP gmail servers.

For whatever reason, the main GFW list doesn't include these. All you need to do is add these two lines to your PAC file:

||imap.gmail.com^
||smtp.gmail.com^

As soon as I added those, the mail app was working with gmail. I hope this works for you!

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your information! I'll try this later this night!

Comment: Let me know if it works! Update: I started having problems again, so I switched to outlook. Outlook had no problems at all and always gets my gmail messages. I think the Mail app itself does something strange.

Comment: Pity that the G List doesn't include those two lines.